# Native gallery custom html output

Tags: functions, filters, shortcode, gallery

I've added image gallery to my page via ***Add Media > Create Gallery***. I don’t want to output default html of the gallery, neither are sufficient options to change gallery sortcode's attributes: `itemtag`, `icontag`, `captiontag` as I want an entirely custom html.

I’ve tried to filter `post_gallery`, grab urls of images that are included as a gallery into that page and output them:

```
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'my_name_page_gallery', 10, 2 );
function my_name_page_gallery($output, $attr) {
    $output = get_post_gallery_images();
    return $output;
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Maximum function nesting level of ‘512’ reached, aborting! in
>   /wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 234

What am I doing wrong? How do I get gallery images’ urls and output custom html?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for, [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_gallery_images/)?  **get_post_gallery_images()**.

This is the example for that page.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpdocs_show_gallery_image_urls' );

/**
* Show image URLs below the content
*/
function wpdocs_show_gallery_image_urls( $content ) {

    global $post;

    // Only do this on singular items
    if( ! is_singular() )
        return $content;

    // Make sure the post has a gallery in it
    if( ! has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) )
        return $content;

    // Retrieve the first gallery in the post
    $gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post );
    $image_list = '<ul>';

    // Loop through each image in each gallery
    foreach( $gallery as $image_url ) {
        $image_list .= '<li>' . '<img src="' . $image_url . '">' . '</li>';
    }
    $image_list .= '</ul>';

    // Append our image list to the content of our post
    $content .= $image_list;

    return $content;
}
```